# How to pass the length of each element in an R vector to the substr function?

Tags: r, substr

I have the following vector.

```
v <- c('X100kmph','X95kmph', 'X90kmph', 'X85kmph', 'X80kmph',
       'X75kmph','X70kmph','X65kmph','X60kmph','X55kmph','X50kmph',
       'X45kmph','X40kmph','X35kmph','X30kmph','X25kmph','X20kmph',
       'X15kmph','X10kmph')
```

I want to extract the digits representing speed. They all start at the 2nd position, but end at different places, so I need `(length of element i) - 4` as the ending position.

The following doesn't work as `length(v)` returns the length of the vector and not of each element.

```
vnum <- substr(v, 2, length(v)-4)
```

Tried `lengths()` as well, but doesn't work.

**How can I supply the length of each element to `substr`?**

**Context**:

`v` actually represents a character column (called `Speed`) in a tibble which I'm trying to mutate into the corresponding numeric column.

```
mytibble <- mytibble %>%
  mutate(Speed = as.numeric(substr(Speed, 2, length(Speed) - 4)))
```

Comment: You need to use `nchar()` instead of `length()`. `substr(v, 2, nchar(v)-4)`.

Comment: Great. That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `nchar()` instead of `length()` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086541/how-to-pass-the-length-of-each-element-in-an-r-vector-to-the-substr-function#comment108070500_61086541) by tmfmnk does the trick!

```
vnum <- substr(v, 2, nchar(v)-4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract the digits, then here is another option

```
vnum <- gsub("\\D","",v)
```

such that

```
> vnum
 [1] "100" "95"  "90"  "85"  "80"  "75"  "70"  "65"  "60"  "55" 
[11] "50"  "45"  "40"  "35"  "30"  "25"  "20"  "15"  "10"
```